# Just lost 2 rep points with no record

Tags: discussion, reputation, lost-reputation

I just noticed my rep drop by 2 points while I was browsing SO. I curiously went to check the recent rep logs and saw I had just got an *upvote* on an answer, but I had already hit the rep cap. The last downvote I received was 10 hours ago.

What could have caused this? https://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows a rep equal to before the drop of 2. I don't care about the rep, but I'm rather reporting this in case there's a bug.

```
-- 2010-12-20 rep +215  = 5695      
 2   4481029 (10)
 1   4493939 (15)
 3   4494930 (-2)
 1   4476015 (15)
 2   4494204 (10)
 2   4490198 (10)
 1   4494204 (15)
 2   4499011 (10)
 1   4499172 (15)
 1   4499011 (15)
 3   4499172 (-2)
 3   4499172 (-2)
 3   4499172 (-2)
 2   4499726 (10)
 2   4499750 (10)
 3   4499172 (-2)
 2   4498966 (10)
 2   4499726 (10)
 2   4499172 (10)
 2   4500181 (10)
 2   4500181 (10)
 1   4499750 (15)
 2   4499172 (10)
 2   4500181 (10)
 2   4499172 (10)
 2   4500577 (10)
 2   4500478 (10)
 2   4500478 (10)
 2   4500478 (10)
 2   4500478 (10)
 2   4500577 (10)
 2   4500577 (10)
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500577 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 1   4500577 [15]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4499011 [0]
     2   4499172 [0]
 2   4499172 [0]
 1   4359961 [15]
 2   4498966 [0]
 2    791561 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4503696 [0]
 2   4503696 [0]
 2   4503696 [0]
 2   4503696 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4500478 [0]
 2   4503696 [0]
 2   4500577 [0]
     2   4481029 [0]
 1   4481029 [15]
 2   4504677 [0]
 2   4504677 [0]
 2   4504677 [0]
 2   4504677 [0]
 2   4493939 [0]
# Lost 2 points some time here
-- 2010-12-21 rep +335  = 6030      
 2   4505361 (10)
 2   4500478 (10)
 2   4500181 (10)
 2   4504677 (10)
 2   4504677 (10)
-- 2010-12-22 rep +50   = 6080
```

Reported rep now is 6078, whereas the report shows 6080.

Comment: I encountered this issue too, I guess it was because of the accepted edit I made which earned me 2points and then someone removed the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a down-vote on a post that's now been deleted. Rep recovery/loss from deleted posts doesn't happen immediately.

If you've not deleted anything yourself then either a question you answered was deleted or a moderator deleted your post.

Are you missing any questions or answers from your profile page? I know it's pretty hard to spot, but you never know.

The other alternative is that two posts that you downvoted (-1 for each) have now been deleted.

Comment: I don't recall any posts with total vote count of -1.

Comment: @marcog - It could be that posts you down-voted have been deleted.

Comment: I see, yes that would make sense.

Comment: Wait, it just hit me: if that was the case, wouldn't *I* *gain* 2 rep? It would have to be posts on which I gained points that were deleted, and since the only way of obtaining 2 points is from accepting an answer the only valid action is deleting a question I asked. Not so?

Comment: @marcog - Yes you have gained 2 points. Your "headline" figure (unrecalculated) is 6078. Add 2 from the deleted posts you downvoted gives 6080.